# Retrieving information from using select-option tag with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have four select options

```
name, region, year, month
```

What I want is when user select name and hit submit it should return the data related to that name ignoring region, year, month if it is not provided by user. when I select name and year then it should  return the data related to that name and year ignoring others. It should work so on, in any selection. Please Help

Comment: Welcome to SO. [What you have tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?? [Stack Overflow is not a research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/177097). Please tell us what you have tried so far and where you have stucked.

Answer (score 0):

Chained selects is what you need:

http://www.appelsiini.net/2010/jquery-chained-selects

Answer (score 0):

Just with PHP this seems to be impossible to do in an easy way. What you have to do is to check your submitted (i.e. $_POST) value arrays for `empty()` and build the mysql-query according to that, appending more WHERE-clauses when the user selected a field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
if($_POST['name'])
{ 
 $subqry.="name='".$_POST['name']."'";
 $and="and";
}
if($_POST['region'])
{
 $subqry.=$and." region='".$_POST['region']."'";
 $and="and";
}
if($_POST['month'])
{
 $subqry.=$and." month='".$_POST['month']."'";
 $and="and";
}
if($_POST['year'])
{
 $subqry.=$and." year='".$_POST['year']."'";
}


$sqlqry = "select * from tablename where ".$subqry;
```